# Using pkg to create .exe failing because of robotjs

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install, yarnpkg, robotjs

So I am using pkg to create an executable of a fairly simple node/express application. I am having issues with the npm module robotjs, whenever I create my exe, it wont run because of the following error:

```
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1740
  throw error;
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
at process.dlopen (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:2071:69)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1131:18)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1719:31)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\visortokey\node_modules\robotjs\index.js:1:77)
at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1794:22)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
```

When I remove calls to robotjs within my project it works just fine.

I have the following in my package.json

```
{
"name": "project",
"bin": "src/app.js",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "src/app.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node src/app.js",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"pkg": {
"assets": [
  "templates/**/*",
  "public/**/*"
],
"targets": [
  "node14"
],
"outputPath": "dist"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.17.1",
"hbs": "^4.1.2",
"http": "0.0.1-security",
"nodemon": "^2.0.14",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"pkg": "^5.3.3",
"robotjs": "git+https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs.git",
  "socket.io": "^4.3.1"
},
"devDependencies": {}
}
```

When I run pkg . --debug, the final error it shows is:

```
[debug] prebuild-install 

 failed[C:\Users\Documents\visortokey\node_modules\robotjs\build\Release\robotjs.node 
 ]:
 Error: spawnSync 
C:\npm\node_modules\pkg\node_modules\.bin\prebuild-install 
ENOENT
```

Any ideas? I have tried updating the robotjs prebuild-install, adding a local resource of robotjs in my dist folder, installing robotjs from npm rather than github, adding robotjs module as an asset but whatever I do, I cannot clear the issue.

Comment: Might also be worth raising over on the [robotjs issue tracker](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/issues)?

Comment: Thanks @mike pomax kamermans. I'm really lost with this one. I have tried so many things, installing pkg globally, changing node versions, changing robotjs versions but the problem is always there. Why does robotjs install successfully but fails at prebuild-install when packaging. I'm so confused 

Comment: I've never used it, so I won't be able to help there, but did you file that issue so that the people most suited to help, are aware of the problem you're facing?